# Prometheus / Grafana - How can I create a graph that shows me the variation of proposals contracted per employee?

Tags: graph, counter, prometheus, grafana

In my SpringBoot Application using Prometheus, I created a metric type Count that brings me the following information :-

```
pre_analise_executadas_total{id_partner="parceiro1",id_person="pessoa2",id_product="produto1",id_proposal="proposta3", id_employee="operador1",} 1.0
```

For each new proposal generated, prometheus presents me with this information and assigns a value of **1** to the counter, because in this combination of attributes each proposal will be unique.

How can I generate a graph in **Grafana** that shows the variation in the number of proposals contracted per employee each day of the month?